# How to print whether each string in a list is in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a list of search terms and a pandas dataframe, what is the most pythonic way to print whether the search term is present in the target dataframe?

```
search_terms = ["red", "blue", "green", "orange"]
```

input_df looks like...

```
    color  count
0     red     15
1    blue     39
2  yellow     40
3   green     21
```

I want to see...

```
red = true
blue = true
green = true
orange = false
```

I know how to filter the input_df to include only search_terms. This doesn't alert me to the fact that "orange" was not located in the input_df. The search_terms could contain hundreds or thousands of strings.

```
color = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green']
count = [15,39,40,21]

input_dict = dict(color=color, count=count)
input_df = pd.DataFrame(data=input_dict)

found_df = input_df[input_df['color'].isin(search_terms)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
out = dict(zip(search_terms, pd.Series(search_terms).isin(input_df['color'])))
```

Or:

```
out = dict(zip(search_terms, np.isin(search_terms, input_df)) )
```

Output:

```
{'red': True, 'blue': True, 'green': True, 'orange': False}
```

Comment: Thanks I used the first option and it works perfectly.